# Update constraint in cellforRow

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I am updating the constraint in CellForRow method.After updating the constraint which method should I Call, setUpdateConsraint(), or layoutIfNeeded()? or simply return the cell. No need to call any method ?

Comment: call cell.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: call layoutIfNeeded() for update the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Call `layoutIfNeeded()` and also implement the method `prepareForReuse` method where you need to reset your constraints.

For example:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    yourConstraint.constant = defaultConstraint
}
```

Why this is neeeded: it will randomly use the constraints later when you scroll since the cells are reused.

Answer (score 0):

`cellForRowAt` is a perfectly acceptable place to update the constraint, and then simply return the cell. You don't need to call anything else:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SCellA", for: indexPath) as! SCellA

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.theLabel.text = "\(indexPath)"
    cell.theHeightConstraint.constant = indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? 40 : 100

    return cell
}
```

Comment: *"constraint does not gets update"* --- what do you mean? You don't *see* it? Do you get an error or warning message? Is some other code also changing the `.constant`? If you step through in debug, what values do you get? You need to provide much more information.

Comment: After updating the constraint constant value calling updateConstraint() working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)**

is the Right method to update constraint.
Add your code to update constraint inside this method.